# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' using MatTableDataSource from angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter

I am trying to build a filter for a table in angular:

```
<div>
    <input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" matInput placeholder="Filter">
</div>
```

In that part of the code I am getting this error:

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me also
<input (keyup)="filter($any($event.target).value)">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm it worked on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you did not declare `applyFilter()` function in the TS file. I have used the exactly the same HTML and I have used `applyFilter()` function like below=>

```
 applyFilter(data){
   console.log(data);
 }
```

and in console, it is showing the result. On the other hand hand, if you still facing the problem with `(keyup)` you can use `(input)` too. After trying all of them, if you still face problem then check the `app.module.ts` file and find `FormsModule` is imported or not.
**Note:** 1.

1. Code for `(keyup)` [Stackblitz
   Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-input-jbzr7r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).
2. Code for `(input)` [Stackblitz
   Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fail-to-render-jonjai?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: I applied your solutions, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cj4mi4?file=src/app/hojaexcelcomponent.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cj4mi4?file=src/app/hojaexcelcomponent.ts

Comment: @arnoldogonzalez there is an error in stackblitz demo in both link. :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
<input (keyup)="filter($any($event.target).value)">
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this issue by adding property in tsconfig.json under angularCompilerOptions option

```
"strictDomEventTypes":false
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Try to avoid including images, instead paste the actual code and format it.